# Disable the second input field if the first input field is filled else if the second input field is filled disable the first field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

There are three fields:
1.video URL
2.JPath
3.Prefix

If the user is typing in video Url I want to disable the JPath and if the user is typing in JPath video URL should be disabled and whenever the JPath is enabled the Prefix should be enabled. How to implement this in react?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Do you have any code yet? You could use variables in the `state` property of a component and check these variables to enable/disable fields. Whenever you use `this.setState()` to change one of these variables the component is re-rendered and will update the display.